# Xcode9.3.1でビルドしようとするとPBXCp Errorが出てしまいます。

Tags: ios, xcode

エラー内容は以下の通りです。 No such file or directory　と最後に出ていますので、ファイルが見つからないという事？

```
CpResource Meditation\ Timer/Meditation\ Timer /Users/hogehoge/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Meditation_Timer-bspafxtlmrawwbfuccsltzydslqp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Meditation\ Timer.app/Meditation\ Timer
cd "/Users/hogehoge/Amazon Drive/Meditation Timer"
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/hogehoge/Amazon\ Drive/Meditation\ Timer/Meditation\ Timer/Meditation\ Timer /Users/hogehoge/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Meditation_Timer-bspafxtlmrawwbfuccsltzydslqp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Meditation\ Timer.app
```

error: /Users/hogehoge/Amazon Drive/Meditation Timer/Meditation Timer/Meditation Timer: No such file or directory

また、これまでに試した解決方法は、以下の３点です。
１：derived dataの削除  Xcodeのメニューバー　→ file → project as settingからファイルに入って全て削除しました。
２：Xcodeのメニューバー　→ Product → clean build folder
3:Copy Bundle Resourcesの確認　→ ここには、エラーとなっているファイルがありませんでした。

上記３つの方法でもまだビルド出来ずにエラーが出てしまいます。

※error: /Users/hogehoge/Amazon Drive/Meditation Timer/Meditation Timer/Meditation Timer: No such file or directory

ここでMeditation Timerが3回繰り返されてしまっているのが、おかしいのかもしれません。なぜ、このようになってしまっているのか調べましたが、まだ不明です。

解決方法を教えて下さい。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/128790

Answer (score 0):

Xcodeのソースの左側の、プロジェクトビューワーで、一番上の青いプロジェクトアイコンを選ぶと、ソースコードを表示していた部分が、プロジェクトの設定を行う画面に変わります。

その左側にTARGETSという部分があると思うので、作りたいアプリケーションをクリックして下さい。

アプリケーションを選んだら、隣のペインの上部中央からやや右に`Build Phases`という項目があるのでそれをクリックします。

その下の部分に`Copy Bundle Resource`という▲があると思うので、ここを展開して、赤くなっているファイルがないか確認して下さい。

赤くなっているファイルがあれば、そのファイルが存在しないためのエラーだと思います。